# getting lost in Using which() and regex in R

Tags: r, regex

OK, I have a little problem which I believe I can solve with `which` and `grepl` (alternatives are welcome), but I am getting lost:

```
my_query<- c('g1', 'g2', 'g3')
my_data<- c('string2','string4','string5','string6')
```

I would like to return the index in `my_query` matching in `my_data`. In the example above, only 'g2' is in `mydata`, so the result in the example would be `2`.

Comment: Some ideas: `sapply(my_query, grepl, x = my_data)`, `sapply(my_query, grepl, x = my_data)`. You could wrap the second one in `which()`.

Comment: Thanks, Gregor. I think the 2 examples are identical. Also, it returns me a matrix, as you say, I would need to wrap it in such a way to get the column number of the matrix I think

Comment: Sorry, meant the second one to be `sapply(my_query, function(q) any(grepl(q, my_data)))`, which leads to `which(sapply(my_query, function(q) any(grepl(q, my_data))))`. But more-or-less what Zheyuan posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that there is no easy way to do this without a loop. For each element in `my_query`, we can use either of the below functions to get `TRUE` or `FALSE`:

```
f1 <- function (pattern, x) length(grep(pattern, x)) > 0L

f2 <- function (pattern, x) any(grepl(pattern, x))
```

For example,

```
f1(my_query[1], my_data)
# [1] FALSE
f2(my_query[1], my_data)
# [1] FALSE
```

Then, we use `*apply` loop to apply, say `f2` to all elements of `my_query`:

```
which(unlist(lapply(my_query, f2, x = my_data)))
# [1] 2
```

---

> Thanks, that seems to work. To be honest, I preferred to your one-line original version. I am not sure why you edited with creating another function to call afterwards with `*apply`. Is there any advantage as compared to `which(lengths(lapply(my_query, grep, my_data)) > 0L)`?

Well, I am not entirely sure. When I read `?lengths`:

```
 One advantage of ‘lengths(x)’ is its use as a more efficient
 version of ‘sapply(x, length)’ and similar ‘*apply’ calls to
 ‘length’.
```

I don't know how much more efficient that `lengths` is compared with `sapply`. Anyway, if it is still a loop, then my original suggestion `which(lengths(lapply(my_query, grep, my_data)) > 0L)` is performing 2 loops. My edit is essentially combining two loops together, hopefully to get some boost (if not too tiny).

You can still arrange my new edit into a single line:

```
which(unlist(lapply(my_query, function (pattern, x) any(grepl(pattern, x)), x = my_data)))
```

or

```
which(unlist(lapply(my_query, function (pattern) any(grepl(pattern, my_data)))))
```

Comment: Thanks, Zheyuan Li, that seems to work. To be honest, I preferred your one-liner original version ;) I am not sure why you edited with creating another function to call afterwards with *apply. Is there any advantage as compared to "which(lengths(lapply(my_query, grep, my_data)) > 0)" ?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on a comment posted initially by @Gregor you could try:

```
which(colSums(sapply(my_query, grepl, my_data)) > 0)
#g2 
# 2
```

The function `colSums` is vectorized and represents no problem in terms of performance. The `sapply()` loop seems inevitable here, since we need to check each element within the query vector. The result of the loop is a logical matrix, with each column representing an element of `my_query` and each row an element of `my_data`. By wrapping this matrix into `which(colSums(..) > 0)` we obtain the index numbers of all columns that contain at least one `TRUE`, i.e., a match with an entry of `my_data`.

Comment: Well, you can avoid `sapply` by: `r = regexpr(paste(my_query, collapse="|"), my_data); match(regmatches(my_data, r), my_query)`

Comment: @Frank Interesting. Thanks for pointing out this possibility. I personally find it somewhat too complicated, but it is true that a loop is not used there. At least I used a cautious wording ("...seems inevitable"), but I should have realized that there are always alternatives in coding. In another answer there have been discussions concerning a similar solution about nested loops (because of the implicit loop within `lengths`). In that sense, `colSums` combined with `grepl` looks like a good alternative to me.

Comment: Yeah, I would use your approach here, I think, mostly because I don't like leaning to heavily on regex tricks.